# Trying to Redirect. 302 Error. HTTP CLIENT 4.1.1

Tags: java, jsp, httpclient, http-status-code-302

```
Edited:- Updated One
```

What's wrong with this code. Now I am getting error on setRedirectStrategy as

`The method setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy(){}) is undefined for the type DefaultHttpClient`

and error on DefaultRedirectStrategy as

```
DefaultRedirectStrategy cannot be resolved to a type
```

and error on super as the same as above one

```
DefaultRedirectStrategy cannot be resolved to a type
```

And I am trying to redirect as I am always getting 302 error. So is this the right way to do it. Any example will be appreciated..

```
<%@ page language="java" import="org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient,org.apache.http.HttpResponse,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,java.io.OutputStream,java.net.HttpURLConnection,java.net.URL,java.util.Collection,org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthenticationException,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.MalformedChallengeException,org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.DefaultHttpParams,org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpParams,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScheme,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthPolicy,org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient,org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope,org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod,org.w3c.dom.*,javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder,javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory,java.net.*,java.io.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
String a_Url = request.getParameter( "url" ) ;

URL url = new URL (a_Url);
String encoding = new String(
         org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64   
            (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8("test:test"))
          );


HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in   = 
    new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
   out.println(line);
}

%>
<%
DefaultHttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {                
    public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)  {
        boolean isRedirect=false;
        try {
            isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!isRedirect) {
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});


%>
```

Comment: It looks like you copy and pasted this code. What is the original problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @jtoberon, I copied this code from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658721/httpclient-4-error-302-how-to-redirect/5046466#5046466) only some part from DefaultHttpClient..  
. I am getting `302 error The document has moved` as response back from the sever from the proxy code. So that's why I am using this DefaultHttpClient code from that post. Let me know If I am doing anything wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's quite simple: you're missing HttpContext in your import statement at the top of this code block. Add `org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext` somewhere in the comma-separated `import` list.

As for whether this is the right way to do it, what's it? Can you say more about your application?

Comment: that got resolved... thanks.. but I am getting error on setRedirectStrategy as `Syntax error on token "setRedirectStrategy", = expected after this token` and error on isRedirected as `The method isRedirected(HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpContext) is undefined for the type HttpServlet`. I am always getting 302 error as The document has moved.. so thought to redirect to that url. so that's why I am trying to check the response code.

Comment: You have an extra ! at the beginning of your scriptlet.

Comment: thanks for replying back, I have updated the question as the answer provided by you, now I am getting those error as I updated in the question..

Comment: Add `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy` somehwere in the comma-separated `import` list.

Comment: If I am adding this import than I am getting red line on this import as `The import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
final DefaultRedirectStrategy instance =new LaxRedirectStrategy();
httpClientBuilder.setRedirectStrategy(instance);
```

if you just want to override 302