# HttpPost -> Redirect -> Location or body of response needed

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpresponse, http-status-code-302

Here is Java code that POSTs data to a website and than gets redirected as a response (status 302). It works perfectly on my PC (Eclipse, Java, Ubuntu), it does exactly what I want it to do.

I tried quite everything to post the code functionality but I just am not able to.

Java code:

```
// Preparing the CLIENT and POST Method
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://na.leagueoflegends.com/ladders/solo-5x5");

  try {
     // Add your POST METHOD attributes
     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("op", "Search"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player", "Jaiybe"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ladder_id", "3"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form_build_id",
           "form-526370b788622996caa3669e7b975ccf"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form_id",
           "ladders_filter_form"));
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

     // Execute HTTP Post Request
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

     // RESPONE THAT WORKS WITH JAVA
     System.out.println("Location:");
     String LocationHeader = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();
     System.out.println(LocationHeader);
     System.out.println();

     // To get the BODY I would have to parse that again - since its not REDIRECTING automatically
     HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost(LocationHeader);
     response = httpclient2.execute(httppost2);
     System.out.println("And EVEN the response body:");
     System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

Code does:

1. Posts
2. Gets Redirected - gets header of Location
3. Parses the Location

And I need android to do the same. Either "Location" or body of repsonse, is ok, I dont need both.

The post: http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/httppost-clientprotocolexception-t56118.html

Comment: Have you tried using the Apache Commons HttpClient? In my experience it gives you greater flexibility and it should handle most redirects automatically (there are some exceptions though). If you're still running into the same issues after that, you could try implementing your own 'redirector' to override standard behavior.

Comment: @MH.: uhm, OP **is** using HttpClient.

Comment: Ah shoot, I'm getting things mixed up. Sorry about that. Nonetheless, have you tried handling the redirects manually using your own [RedirectHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html). What's interesting to me though is that you're basically getting an `IOException` and not a `HttpException`, as `ClientProtocolException` subclasses the former. You may also want to check for other Location headers, not just the first - see [this blog post](http://blog.kosev.net/2011/01/follow-302-redirects-with.html).

Comment: Hello to all that are trying to help me - I appreciate that a LOT (trust me) :). well the point is, I have no idea why I am getting this exceptions or whatever because the code with same functionality works in java flawless - with no exceptions and does exactly what I want.. And I have no idea why the java httpclient acts differently than the httpclient in android - I mean if I knew what is causing this I would set it up somehow but I have no idea... The JAVA jource that runs perfectly can be found here:

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/httppost-clientprotocolexception-t56118.html ... I taught like ok, maybe the customredirecthandler could help - but as you say Its an IOException and I have no idea what could cause that :( damin I spent so much time here I dont even have an idea what day it is today :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem!

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version",
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0);
```

Just changing this one line - version 1_0 works and 1_1 does not. Don't ask me why :)

Thank you all!

Comment: I second this answer. There seems to be a problem somewhere. The same exact code on Android and on plain Java, gives different results with HTTP 1.1, whereas with 1.0 it works.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code. The location in the header is missing, because the page has already redirected. So we can disable redirection to get the location tag.

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this after you create your http client so that it follows your redirect

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects", true);
```

Comment: that did not work :( still the same exception - clientprotocolexception

Comment: Can you post the stack dump of your exception? Perhaps you can chuck a version of your code, along with the exception seen as a ghist on git hub.

Comment: hello danny, please explain me once more what you need me to do

Comment: You need to get the stack trace from LogCat and edit your question to include the collected logs

Comment: My Friend :( I have tryed Logcat but no informative was inside .. Im a news - I agree on that, and I dont seem to find the way. I know this is not only a question and answer thing - so Im ready to pay you for your time - or to anybody who would help me .. Just please help me run that god damn code without any exceptions :( I found another articles about how android handles redirecting and that it throws exceptions when other code than 2XX is received - but NOTHING helped :( if you have paypal - solve it and tell me your price please