# How to follow redirects for POST in Apache HttpClient 5.1

Tags: java, redirect, https, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm looking how to follow redirects for POST requests as POST in **Apache HttpClient 5.1**

By default, only **GET** requests resulting in a redirect are automatically followed. If a **POST** requests is answered with either HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently) or with 302 (Moved Temporarily) – the redirect is **not** automatically followed. This is specified by the [HTTP RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3)

There are usecases, however, when POST request has to be redirected as POST. In such cases, the default behavior has to be changed in order to relax the strict HTTP specification.

With **Apache HttpClient 4.5** this could be easily achieved by replacing [DefaultRedirectStrategy](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/rel/v4.5.12/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRedirectStrategy.java) with [LaxRedirectStrategy](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/rel/v4.5.12/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/LaxRedirectStrategy.java) or with your own custom implementation of [RedirectStrategy](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/rel/v4.5.12/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/client/RedirectStrategy.java) interface. Examples:

- [Apache HttpClient 4.5 redirect POST request to GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312858/apache-httpclient-4-5-redirect-post-request-to-get-request)
- https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-redirect-on-http-post

In **Apache HttpClient 5.1** this doesn't work anymore. The [RedirectStrategy](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.1.x/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/protocol/RedirectStrategy.java) interface changed and no longer contain ***getRedirect*** method, ***LaxRedirectStrategy*** implementation has also been removed.

Is there a way to override default POST redirect behavior in **Apache HttpClient 5.1** similar or as simple as in **HttpClient 4.5**?

Comment: By chance, did you find an answer for this? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: Hi @MelvinSy thanks you for taking interest in this question. I posted my reply as an answer, hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 6):

Since no one replied so far I'll post my own findings as an answer.

One of internal servers in my company that handled file uploads had to be converted from HTTP to HTTPS. Additional requirement was: if someone forgot to update their URLs and uploaded files using HTTP - their uploads have to be properly redirected to HTTPS and processed too.

That was easy to do with **HttpClient 4.5** (see the original question) but with **HttpClient 5.1**. If the clients sent POST requests over HTTP to HTTPS server - they were redirected (301 Moved Permanently), POST was converted to GET, and then rejected by the server.

Examining the source code I found that in version **5.1** HttpClient developers decided to strictly enforce [HTTP RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) and removed the very possibility to override or relax the redirect strategy.

In **HttpClient 5.1.x** request redirection is handled by [RedirectExec](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.1.x/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/RedirectExec.java) class, where the logic of replacing **POST** with **GET** for certain status codes (302, 302, 303) is hardcoded:

[image]

That made client side solution rather cumbersome and expensive. However, since I had full control over the server I decided to fix the problem on the server side.

It was done by reconfiguring the NGNIX server to return **"308 Permanent Redirect"** on HTTP to HTTPS redirects, instead of default **"301 Moved Permanently"**

```
server {
    listen 80      default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Not exactly the solution I was hoping for, but works great for my use case, and is much simpler than writing a custom implementation of [RedirectExec](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.1.x/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/RedirectExec.java)