# Keep POST method after a 302 redirect response

Tags: java, redirect, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-status-code-302

I am building a Junit test, in which I have to perform a HTTP Post to a Spring app. This app is secured by a CAS, so each request to this app is redirected to the CAS, which allow or not the request. If it does, a 302 response is sent.
I configured my code to follow the redirection:

```
 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                    .build();
            final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(path);

httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/***+xml");
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic ***");
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(myObject.toString()));
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

The thing is that the POST request, when redirected, becomes a GET, which is not what I want. Is there a way avoid that ?
By the way, when I perform the request with Postman, it works fine, and the POST is still a POST after the redirection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache HttpClient 4.5 redirect POST request to GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312858/apache-httpclient-4-5-redirect-post-request-to-get-request)