# Copy Contents of HttpMethod to another HttpMethod

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, redirect, header

I have been tryig to handle a redirect(302) in java code and now that I am done doing it by my code. I ran into an other problem in which after login, on click on any link I get logged out. So I checked my TCP Stream through wireshark and found that there are few `HeaderRequests` missing. After implementation of my code, Http Header are as follows :

```
GET /index.php/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.28.161.31
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111109 CentOS/3.6-3.el5.centos Firefox/3.6.24
Cookie: PHPSESSID=d488eea5e85afc8ec526c1a749e7ab20; path=/
Referrer: http://10.28.161.31
Cookie: $Version=0; PHPSESSID=d488eea5e85afc8ec526c1a749e7ab20; $Path=/ ???
```

and original Http Headers are as follows :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.28.161.31
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111109 CentOS/3.6-3.el5.centos Firefox/3.6.24
Referer: http://10.28.161.31/index.php
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=978ee1e3b3696743c5c8f507a2ec7212
```

According to my observation, I did not copied the Header's content properly and that's why it is logging out quickly. So my question is that, how can I copy the complete content of `HttpMethod` to another `HttpMethod`? If any one can provide a code snippet or an example/tutorial would be great or If any one can give me a heads up on where I am doing things wrong, that would be appreciable.

My implementation is right here :

```
private HttpMethod loadHttp302Request(HttpMethod method, HttpClient client,
                int status, String urlString) throws HttpException, IOException {
    if (status!=302)
        return null;
    String[] url = urlString.split("/");        
    HttpMethod theMethod = new GetMethod(urlString + method.getResponseHeader("Location").getValue());
    theMethod.setRequestHeader("Cookie", method.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
                    .getValue());
    theMethod.setRequestHeader("Referrer",url[0]+"//"+url[2]);
    int _status = client.executeMethod(theMethod);
    return theMethod;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient can automatically handle the redirects if you set the strategy. Follow this post on usage example [Httpclient 4, error 302. How to redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658721/httpclient-4-error-302-how-to-redirect)

Comment: And exactly how would you make a translation b/w HttpClient and DefaultHttpClient???