# How to authenticate with httpclient 4.3

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've just upgraded to org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient 4.3. Previously I created a client and did pre-emptive authentication like this:

```
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpRequestBase request = new HttpGet(url);
request.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate( new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password), "UTF-8", false));
```

Now that this is deprecated I have to create a client and authenticate like this:

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

clientBuilder = clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
```

However instead of authenticating and making a successful GET I get a 302 in response. I think this could be fixed by setting pre-emptive authentication, but I can't find how. Maybe I have authentication in this second example all wrong?

Can I get some pointers, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Httpclient 4, error 302. How to redirect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658721/httpclient-4-error-302-how-to-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether this is actually a real problem.

HTTP 302 is a redirection. You need to follow the redirect.

Comment: Thanks. I realise that. With the previous client code I didn't have to follow the redirect and I want to get the same behaviour.

Comment: @PaulGrenyer: All 4.x version of HttpClient handle redirects automatically by default. You cannot be getting 302 status to a GET unless redirects are explicitly disabled. Either details are incomplete / incorrect or something just is very wrong. A wire log of the session would help a lot