# Http Post request not working in apache Http client, where as working with Advanced Rest Client

Tags: post, httpclient

I am trying to call a authentication URL using apache HttpPost, passing all the request parameters like userid, pwd hardcoded for proof of concept purpose. I found it is not working with a response code of 302.
However if I submit the same request from chrome PostMan or Advanced RestClient it is found to be working with 200 response code. I am able to get the correct response of the Post call.

Want to understand If I am doing anything wrong or my understanding about RestClient (POSTMAN/Advanced RestClient) is wrong.

Please suggest

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A [HTTP 302 response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is a request to redirect.

When Postman receives this response, [it will automagically redirect](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/186) to the URL provided in the HTTP 302 response - you'll see this if you install Postman Interceptor.

Apache HTTPClient doesn't do this automatic redirection - so you see the raw HTTP 302 redirect. [Use the location in the HTTP 302 response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658721/httpclient-4-error-302-how-to-redirect) to perform the redirect.

Comment: Now, in a similar scenario, I'm getting a HTTP 503 HTTPClient, but Postman is getting a HTTP 200 response. Any suggestions? :)